Ansible playbook "chmod" files and folders works on small directory trees, but dies on large directory trees
We're trying to keep the files and folders all set to the same group so that all users connecting to our SFTP chrooted directory get access to the same folders.  We're using a default group assigned at login for all users, so that's why we're trying to keep the same group.  Not our choice, this was a vendor requirement on the default group.  Some users are not setting proper group/perms when they're creating folders or writing files.  Our default is to write files at 0755, and we need to override that in this chrooted file system.  We don't want to change any hidden files and folders.  The following Ansible tasks work fine when touching a small file system, but when assigned to the larger file system we get the following error:

...
TASK [manage_directories : Recursively change ownership | chmod_files_folders_recursively.yml 21]
ERROR! A worker was found in a dead state

It seems as though it's running out of memory or some stack overflow.  We've confirmed the task starts in an strace, but are not seeing memory go much higher on the machine while watching htop.  Again, it works fine on a smaller sub-set of files/folders, just not the main directory with around 144K objects.


name: Recursively find all files | chmod_files_folders_recursively.yml 1
find:
path: /some/specific/path
file_type: any
hidden: false
recurse: true
register: folder_contents

name: Recursively change ownership | chmod_files_folders_recursively.yml 21
file:
path: "{{ item.path }}"
group: somegroup
mode: '2775'
loop: "{{ folder_contents.files }}"




Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The ansible playbook fails with an "ERROR! A worker was found in a dead state", and I'm unable to determine why.  Even with full verbose debugging, it outputs nothing of value, it's the exact same error statement.
